# Trouble drawing point using Point2D.Double

Tags: java, graphics, shapes, point

I am attempting to read coordinates off a file and use them to draw points using this snippet of code:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    if(scan.next().equals("i")){
        Point2D.Double point = new Point2D.Double(scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble());
        g2.draw(point);
    }
}
```

However, when I do, I get the following error:

```
Map.java:43: error: method draw in class Graphics2D cannot be applied to given 
types;
                                    g2.draw(point);
                                      ^
  required: Shape
  found: Double
  reason: actual argument Double cannot be converted to Shape by method 
invocation conversion
1 error
```

I don't understand why this is.  If I pass two doubles as arguments into the constructor for a Point2D.Double, it should construct a Point2D Shape, and not a double, correct?

Answer (score 3):

[`java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html) does not implement [`java.awt.Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), so you can't use it as an argument to `Graphics2D.draw`. The simplest method would probably be to use [`Rectangle2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html) like so:

```
Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(point.x - 0.5, point.y - 0.5, 1, 1);`
```

This gives you a "point" centered over the point location with unit dimensions.